# efficient an R-like way to compute the row-based percentage for all elements in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` with absolute values. Because I want to show them in percent I have to calculate that. Each row is 100%.

I want to know if my solution is good enough or if there is a more R-like way?

```
df = data.frame(a=sample(100:1000, 3), b=sample(10:500, 3), c=sample(4:300, 3))
df_abs <- df
for (row in rownames(df)) {
    s = sum(df[row,])
    for (col in colnames(df)) {
        df[row, col] <- 100 / s * df[row, col]
        }
}
```

Comment: @Henrik R is so easy and my head so procuderal. ;) Please transform your comment to an answer.

Comment: definitly a duplicate. Sorry. Not founding it depends on my english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `data.frame` contains all numeric values, you can convert it to a matrix and then use `prop.table` (proportion table).

```
m <- as.matrix(df)
prop.table(m, margin = 1) * 100
#             a         b         c
# [1,] 54.76948 37.758347  7.472178
# [2,] 49.86150  8.864266 41.274238
# [3,] 16.66667 56.641604 26.691729
```

And most (all?) the idiomatic solutions for this type of problem are going to involve coercing your `data.frame` to a `matrix` (explicitly or implicitly). For example, you could use `rowSums` or `apply`. Both of which will implicitly coerce to matrix.

```
# result of apply and rowSums is always matrix
df / apply(df, 1, sum) * 100
df / rowSums(df) * 100
```

Comment: Nice to know that this is possible. But it doesn't look like that the `sum()` in each row is `100%`?

Comment: @buhtz The sum is 100. Try `rowSums(prop.table(as.matrix(df_abs), margin=1)*100)`